# What should be done with embedded recommendation request in an otherwise ok question?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18336595/1743811), and it seems to be fine except that in the end the OP says

> PSP[sic]:I bought a[sic] Android Cookbook by Darwin, can anyone suggest other books for beginners?

I mean it's not that the entire question is a recommendation-type question, but he did ask for a book recommendation at the end.

And then I saw an answer to this question which says

> *Android Programming - The Big Nerd Ranch Guide* - by Phillips and Hardy
>
> it is very new and helped me alot[sic] understanding stuff like fragments and benefit from the lifecycles.

and nothing else.

So, is the embedded recommendation request fine? Or should it be removed from the question? I'm concerned that this question might have the same kind of responses that a regular recommendation-type question would have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question has, in fact, two questions, and one of them is of a type generally discouraged here, it makes sense to simply remove it and let the answerable question remain.

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: I would add that when I do that, I leave the edit summary explaining the change to the OP (to lower the risk of edit wars), typically it looks like like _"shopping /off (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)"_